# SlideShow.js is not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, slideshow

I have created Image Slider using `slideShow.js` as provided in [this msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh920769%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX) article.

It is working in IE 9 and IE 10 but not working in IE 8.

My code is as below:

```
    <head>
      <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <title>Slide Show</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        .size
        {
            height: 300px;
            width: 500px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .lab
        {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            color: #FF0000;
            height: 80px;
            line-height: 20px;
            margin-top: 200px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 480px;
            z-index: 100;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>

            <label class="lab">This is Label</label>
          <div id="slideShowImages">
            <img src="Sample Images/1.jpg" alt="Slide 1" class="size" />
            <img src="Sample Images/2.jpg" alt="Slide 2" class="size"/>
            <img src="Sample Images/3.jpg" alt="Slide 3" class="size"/>    
            <img src="Sample Images/4.jpg" alt="Slide 4" class="size"/>
          </div>  
        </div>
      <script src="slideShow.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

What should I do to make the slide available in IE 8? Please help.

Comment: Define "not working". What's not working? How did you debug the code?

Comment: _Run-time requirements: Internet Explorer 10_

Comment: When I created the HTML I was working in IE 10 then I switched to the IE 8 Compatibility mode using development tool

Comment: Its working in IE 9 @ZippyV

Comment: I hope you've jacked your rates up x10 for IE 8 support. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: I could not get it sir, please clarify.. @cjc343

Comment: I mean that most consumers don't use IE 8, even if they're running XP. Some backwards businesses won't let their employees use a superior browser, so they often require that internal and external sites be written to function 100% in IE 8, or worse. I've just always felt that people who deal with IE 8 and lower should be paid more according to the version they need to support.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with slideshow.js is that it uses `window.addEventListener(...)` which is only implemented in IE9, 10 and 11. Therefore it won't work in IE8.

For slideshows I prefer [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

window.addEventListener() on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)